# A sequence of events is violated in WebViewFragment

Tags: android, android-webview

In https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.java
it is written:

```
/**
 * Called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. Resumes the WebView.
 */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}
/**
 * Called when the fragment is no longer resumed. Pauses the WebView.
 */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mWebView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

I think, there is a mistake. Probably, `onPause` should be replaced with `onResume` and vice versa. If I replace the behaviour in our copy-pasted class, can I get any errors?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the javadocs for the two methods are swapped. Also the method calls in onResume() would probably make more sense the other way. If you're not having any problems with the webview's refresh I see no reason to change your code. But you can try it anyway and see what happens.

Comment: @Crispert, thanks. I swapped these methods and will see what happen. At first attempt it was working right.